# Question banned user meta review queue

Tags: discussion, review, meta, off-topic

On an average day Meta gets 4 or 5 cross posted questions from question banned users on SO. How about a review queue for incoming questions from q-banned users?

All questions from QB users could be redirected into a queue temporarily (say 15 minutes), during which time if the question gets enough off-topic delete votes<sup>*</sup> it never makes it to Meta. If the question doesn't get enough delete votes (either because it is not off topic or because no one is looking at the queue) the question will show up with the rest of the normal questions.

What do you think?

**We would only be judging on topic-ness here, not quality.*

Comment: I agree we should probably have a better process than the current close/delete cycle, but I don't think meta's review queues see enough activity for this to work.

Comment: No way, the should-have-been-posted-on-SO whack-a-mole is [too much fun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134710/159251).

Comment: @JoshCaswell That script is awesome!

Comment: Indeed! (Though note that there seems to be some [agreement that posting C&H answers is less than good](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137587/posting-irrelevant-answers-to-programming-questions-on-meta).)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I disagree with this idea because normally off-topic questions (say programming) are closed within 5 minutes and it is deleted within 30 minutes. So creating a new review queue for this just seems like a waste of time.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like a waste of time. What's wrong with the current close-and-delete process we already use? The questions generally don't stay here *that* long, and sometimes a moderator will delete them within minutes of them being posted. A review queue just makes the process more complicated, and **hides it in the review panel where not as many people will notice it**, taking longer to get rid of it.

This really wouldn't achieve anything. Besides, some of the off-topic questions that end up here *aren't* from question-banned users. What about those? They'll still show in the questions list anyways.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not really sure how this would be a benefit to the Meta community. After all, we're not a bunch of young eyes that will be forever scarred by having to witness an off-topic post hit our screen. Most of us aren't offended by someone failing to read the FAQ, although we do feel a twinge of disappointment. ;)

Instead of being buried in a review queue, we see it right away. In fact, it's become quite a game to me. I can't help but feel a little bummed when I see an off-topic MSO post that *I* didn't get to be the one to flag as very low quality because I missed its deletion by a mere 4 minutes. ;)

In short, these questions don't last very long, maybe 15 minutes tops, before one of the many many moderators on MSO comes along and deletes it. While I encourage you to continue to come up with ideas, this one wouldn't be a good use of developer time.